# gnuplot: how to remove colorbox with splot

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot the following only without the colorbox [image]

As you can see I have tweaked it a bit, removed x/y axes, the title, some borders, but I can't figure out how to remove the colorbox. I would be grateful if someone could take a look and let me know if they have a hint/idea. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Could you edit question and show a relevant sample snippet of the code you used to produce that? It might help answering the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that, by z-axis, you mean that you want to remove the colorbox, then adding the line

```
unset colorbox
```

will remove it from your plot. For future reference, you can find a lot of helpful information on these options by typing `help unset` into the Gnuplot terminal, or for more general support, just `help`.